# Rspec can't create association model with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid

I have two models:

Article model

```
class Article
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps

 field :title, type: String
 field :body, type: String
 default_scope queryable.order_by(:created_at.desc)

 scope :archive, -> { where(:created_at.lte => Time.now - 1.month)}

 embeds_many :comments, as: :commentable
 validates_presence_of :title, :body
end
```

and Comment model

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embedded_in :commentable, polymorphic: true
  embeds_many :answers, as: :commentable, class_name: "Comment"

  default_scope queryable.order_by(:created_at.asc)

  field :body, type: String
  validates_presence_of :body
end
```

my test:

```
describe "Article#show" do
 let!(:article) {FactoryGirl.create(:article)}

 before{visit article_path(article)}
 subject{ page }

 describe "can be commented by other user" do
   before do
     @comment1 = article.comments.create(body: Faker::Lorem.paragraph)
     @comment2 = article.comments.create(body: Faker::Lorem.paragraph)
     @comment3 = article.comments.create(body: Faker::Lorem.paragraph)
   end

  it {should have_selector("div.comment_text", text: @comment1.body)}
  it {should have_selector("div.comment_text", text: @comment2.body)}
  it do
      #save_and_open_page
      should have_selector("div.comment_text", text: @comment3.body)}
    end
 end
```

error:

```
Failure/Error: it {should have_selector("div .comment_text", text: @comment1.body)}
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find css "div .comment_text" with text "Aliquam omnis et ullam quae
   maiores voluptates. Rerum dicta dolores alias voluptates rerum voluptas autem.
   Nemo non quia possimus. Nam commodi odio quia et. Aut non odit ratione quas sit accusantium ut." but there were no matches
```

in view I have partial:

```
=render "shared/comments", model: @article
```

partial(show me right result when comment created from consol):

```
    .comments
    -model.comments.each do |comment|
      .comment
        = image_tag("delete/brian.jpg", class: "avatar")
        .comment-author
          =Faker::Name.name
          %time.comment-date= l(comment.created_at)
        .comment-text
          = comment.body
        -if comment.answers.any?
          -comment.answers.each do |answer|
            .comments-answers
              =image_tag('delete/brian.jpg',class: "avatar")
              .comment-author
                =Faker::Name.name
                %time.comment-date= l(comment.created_at)
              .comment-text= answer.body
```

I can create comments from consol with "Article.first.comments.create" and see it in browser, but when I am testing it, RSpec can`t create any comment for article. I'll  appreciate for any advice.

Comment: Please share the error you're getting

Comment: Hi,shared,on some reason rspec just can`t create comment...

Comment: That error just says you can't find the comment body on your page, not that you couldn't successfully create the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating the comments after you have visited the page. `before` blocks in RSpec are executed in outside first order.

Try moving the `visit article_path(article)` step into the inner `before` block.